# Angular directive to adjust your component Height as per window height Dynamically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, angularjs-directive, directive

Angular directive to adjust the height of your div/components(Elements) Dynamically as per screen

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: using css `height: 100vh`?

Comment: Yes... That also work... but this one is a more efficient method @Eliseo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    import { Directive, ElementRef, Renderer2, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appAutoFullHeight]'
})
export class AutoFullHeightDirective implements AfterViewInit {
  constructor(
    private el: ElementRef,
    private renderer: Renderer2
  ) {
    const windowHeight = window.innerHeight > 600 ? window.innerHeight : 600;
    const calculatedheight = `${windowHeight - 150}px`; // can be simply windowheight but you can do the adjuscement here
    this.renderer.setStyle(this.el.nativeElement, 'height', calculatedheight);

  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {

  }

}
```